# The power consumption of the drive

Tags: power, current

In our company, we are engaged in the construction of a water pumping station.
Station pumps are started by the drive.
We have a software to control the drives that logs the power consumption and the output current and frequency of the drive.
Now we need to calculate the power consumption of the pumping station with the output power of the drive that we have logged.
Our software logs the power, current and frequency of drives every second.
How can this be done?

Comment: well power consumption is energy, i.e. the integral of power. Assuming the power doesn't change too much between the 1 s measurement intervals, simply sum these up?

Comment: Can you write the formula for me?

Comment: \$E = \sum P\cdot \Delta t\$, is that really what you ask for? (I mean, seriously, this is the very definition of power, and integration in discrete time.)

Comment: You need the power consumption and the drive logs power consumption? Job done.